# C: unsigned short stored into buffer after fread from a binary file doesn't match original pattern

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread

I have a binary file filled with 2-byte words following this pattern(in HEX): 0XY0. this is the part of the code where I execute fread and fopen.

```
unsigned short buffer[bufferSize]; 
FILE *ptr;                          //

ptr = fopen(fileIn,"rb");           //

if(ptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to read from file %s because of %s",fileIn,strerror(errno));
    exit(20);
}

size_t readed = fread(buffer,(size_t)sizeof(unsigned short),bufferSize,ptr);
if(readed!=bufferSize)
{
    printf("readed and buffersize are not the same\n");
    exit(100);
}
//---------------------------
```

If I look at any content of the buffer, for example buffer[0], instead of being a short with pattern 0XY0, it is a short with pattern Y00X
Where is my error? is it something regarding endianess?
 of course i checked every element inside buffer. the program execute with no errors.

EDIT: If i read from file with size char instead of short, the content of buffer(obviously changed to char buffer[bufferSize*2];) match the pattern OXYO. So I have that (for example) buffer[0] is 0X and buffer[1] is Y0

Comment: It certainly looks like endianness, as the bytes (I presume you mean `0`  `X` and `Y` are nibble values) are swapped.

Comment: It sounds like endianess.  One check you could do: write a short program that writes out a binary file in the pattern 0XY0, and see if that file reads correctly.

Comment: Ok I will try @DaveGoldberg

Comment: The result of `sizeof` is already a `size_t`, you do not need to cast it.

Comment: Your platform is **little-endian**, which means that the least-significant byte is stored first, period. I.e. unsigned short `0xY00X` is stored as individual bytes `0x0X` `0xY0`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be exactly typical of an endianness mismatch between the program that stored the data into the file and the one that reads it. Remember that mobile phone processors tend to use big-endian representations and laptop little-endian.

Another potential explanation is your file might have been written in text mode by a windows based program that converted the `0x0A` bytes into pairs of `0x0D` / `0x0A`, causing the contents to shift and cause a similar pattern as what you observe.

Instead of reading the file with `fread`, you should read it byte by byte and compute the values according the endianness specified for the file format.

Comment: I was hoping for an easier solution but I'll try something like that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If it is a problem about endianess, I'm wondering why the output pattern isn't 0YX0 instead of Y00X. I'm reading 2 byte a time from the file.

Comment: If i read from file char by char, it does read correctly. For example buffer[0] and buffer[1] are respectevely OX and YO as it should be... Why if i call fread with size short the output is YOOX?

Comment: @Emanuele: `buffer[0]` and `buffer[1]` are unsigned short values, not bytes. The endianness determines in which order the bytes forming multibyte integer words are stored in memory.

Comment: Can you post a hex byte dump of the file contents and print the values in the buffer in hex with `printf("%04X ", buffer[i]);`

Comment: If you have a 16-bit value `X * 256 + Y *16` (which would be 0x0XY0) and swap the two bytes, you end up with `Y + 4096 + X`, or 0xY00X), so, yes, definitely looks like an endian issue.